# Вывод свойств товара по ID товара

Tags: битрикс, интернет-магазин

```
<?
$arSelect = Array("IBLOCK_ID", "ID", "NAME", "PREVIEW_PICTURE", "DETAIL_PAGE_URL","prod_color");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>16, "ID"=>array(12404,10171,10168,10167,10169,10173), "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nTopCount"=>6), $arSelect);

while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
  $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
  $PREVIEW_PICTURE = CFile::GetPath($arFields["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]);
}

?>
```

> Вывожу картинку

```
echo "<img src='"; print_r($PREVIEW_PICTURE); echo "'/>";
```

> Вывожу ссылку на товар

```
<?=$arFields["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"];?>
```

> Вывожу название товара

```
<?=$arFields["NAME"];?>
```

> А вот пытаюсь вывести свойство цвет `'prod_color'` не получается

```
<?=$arFields["prod_color"]?>
```

> Пробывал и так вывести но безрезультатно

```
<?=$arFields["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["prod_color"]["VALUE"]?>
```

Пытаюсь вывести свойство которое добавил, `prod_color` - это цвет. То есть у меня список товаров  в котором отображается ссылка, картинка, цвет и название на каждый товар который есть в списке! Вывожу данные по ID товара.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В $arSelect измените запрос свойства "prod_color" на "PROPERTY_prod_color". Тогда в массиве $arFields значение свойства будет в ключе "PROPERTY_prod_color_VALUE"

Comment: Сделал так, как было написано! Но у меня вышел список свойств каталога то есть название и его ID.



этот код `<?=$arFields["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["prod_color"]["VALUE"]?>` можно написать `<?=$arFields["PROPERTY_prod_color"]?>` ?

Comment: Сделайте перед закрытием while вывод массива $arFields и покажите, что получается

Comment: `Array ( [IBLOCK_ID] => 16 [~IBLOCK_ID] => 16 [ID] => 10167 [~ID] => 10167 [NAME] => FM-Модулятор Bluetooth + Car Charger Earldom ET-M33, Black [~NAME] => FM-Модулятор Bluetooth + Car Charger Earldom ET-M33, Black [PREVIEW_PICTURE] => 153 [~PREVIEW_PICTURE] => 153 [DETAIL_PAGE_URL] => /catalog/avtoaksessuary/10167/ [~DETAIL_PAGE_URL] => /catalog/avtoaksessuary/10167/ [PROPERTY_PROD_COLOR_VALUE] => Зелёный [~PROPERTY_PROD_COLOR_VALUE] => Зелёный [PROPERTY_PROD_COLOR_ENUM_ID] => 155 [~PROPERTY_PROD_COLOR_ENUM_ID] => 155`

Comment: `[PROPERTY_PROD_COLOR_VALUE_ID] => 22313 [~PROPERTY_PROD_COLOR_VALUE_ID] => 22313 [LANG_DIR] => / [~LANG_DIR] => / [CODE] => fm-modulator-bluetooth-car-charger-earldom-et-m33-black [~CODE] => fm-modulator-bluetooth-car-charger-earldom-et-m33-black [EXTERNAL_ID] => a8805c9c-2f47-11e9-98bf-002522ff1850 [~EXTERNAL_ID] => a8805c9c-2f47-11e9-98bf-002522ff1850 [IBLOCK_SECTION_ID] => 170 [~IBLOCK_SECTION_ID] => 170 [IBLOCK_TYPE_ID] => 1c_catalog [~IBLOCK_TYPE_ID] => 1c_catalog`

Comment: `[IBLOCK_CODE] => [~IBLOCK_CODE] => [IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID] => f5ab5b74-07ec-4ff1-b799-3b230cebed99 [~IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID] => f5ab5b74-07ec-4ff1-b799-3b230cebed99 [LID] => s1 [~LID] => s1 )`

Comment: Прошу прощения, у меня был код ниже который пропустил я он выводил все свойства каталога!    По вашему методу у меня не выводит цвет. Главное в массиве $arFields цвет есть!

Comment: Получилось! 

`<? echo $arFields["PROPERTY_PROD_COLOR_VALUE"]?>`

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Есть случаи, когда товара уже нет в номенклатуре, снят с производства, например, и приведенный пример помогает **обойти ошибку "Call to a member function GetProperties() on bool (0)"**. Код ниже позволяет без труда вывести свойства товара и не "положить" цикл на товаре-призраке.

```
$prop_common = CIBlockElement::GetByID('ID_PRODUCT');
$prop = null;

if ($ob = $prop_common->GetNextElement()) {
    $prop = $ob->GetProperties();
}

$sku = '';
if (!is_null($prop)) {
    $sku = $prop['CML2_ARTICLE']['VALUE'];
}
```